# Truncated logs in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When I run my code in the Google Cloud Dataflow, I am getting some tracebacks in the the "Errors" view, but they are truncated.

`(cee7eb663424a856): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 578, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 165, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3442)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3346)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 63, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3261)
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 67, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3205)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 139, in dataflow_worker.operations.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/operations.c:5717)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 220, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:8094)
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 139, in dataflow_worker.operations.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/operations.c:5717)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 395, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13546)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 396, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13500)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5142)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7201)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7609)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 263, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7090)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5288)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 326, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8563)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 395, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13546)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 396, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13500)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5142)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7201)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7609)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 263, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7090)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5288)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 326, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8563)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 395, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13546)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 396, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13500)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5142)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7201)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7609)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 263, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7090)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5288)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 326, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8563)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 395, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13546)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 396, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13500)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5142)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7201)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7609)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 263, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7090)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5288)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 326, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8563)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 395, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13546)
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 396, in dataflow_worker.operations.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/operations.c:13500)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5142)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 267, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7201)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7609)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 263, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:7090)
    self._dofn_simple_invoker(element)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._dofn_simple_invoker (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5288)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(element.value))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 326, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:8563)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/operations.py", line 72, in dataflow_worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/operations.c:3421)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_valu`

Notice how it is truncated at the very end...after around 10220 characters, and it hasn't even gotten to my actual code's stacktrace yet!

If I open the logs panel and go look at the logs, I'm luckily able to see the full thing...including the very last line that is pointing at my code, as well as the actual exception class/message itself.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's a bug report of sorts. I filed it on a JIRA for Apache Beam (the code repository for Google Cloud Dataflow), but they told me to file it on stackoverflow, so I came here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1791

Comment: I am having a similar issue with my logs getting truncated from a large exception in the logging of a cloud run service. Quite annoying and  I have yet to find a fix for this...

Answer (score 1):

The error that shows up in the Dataflow UI is truncated around 10k characters, however if you look in Stackdriver Logging you should be able to see the entire exception.

Comment: Yes, I believe you're restating exactly what I said in the above post, but much more succinctly. :) Sorry, I guess I was trying to file a bug report on the Dataflow UI...I assume this is WAI / Will Not Fix then?